# Call function from child to parent in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xlpagertabstrip

I am using xlpagertabstrip  and I have a parent view controller which has two children (child1, child2).

In my parent view controller, I show a UIActivityViewIndicator but I want to know how to hide that indicator in my child1.

This is my code:

ParentViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
       showActivityIndicator()
       super.viewDidLoad()
}

func showActivityIndicator() {
    //code related to titleview
    navigationItem.titleView = titleView
}

func hideActivityIndicator() {
    navigationItem.titleView = nil
}
```

Child1ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    call_api()
}

func call_api(){
    //code related to api
    //if api is ok, I call hideActivityIndicator()
    let pctrl = ParentViewController()
    pctrl.hideActivityIndicator()
}
```

But that code does not work. How can I solve that?

Comment: `let pctrl = ParentViewController()`That's creating a WHOLE NEW object. That's not the one you think of. You could use Delegate Pattern or Closure to tell your parent to do something.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass `hideActivityIndicator()` from the parent to the child and call it when necessary. So whenever you create your child controller do this:

```
// Parent Controller

childVC.someMethodFromParent = hideActivityIndicator
```

And in your ChildController do this:

```
// Child Controller

internal var someProperty: (() -> Void)!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    call_api()
}

func call_api(){
    //code related to api
    //if api is ok, I call hideActivityIndicator()

   someMethodFromParent()
}
```

This should work

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, the idea is this:
in my child when the api finish to be called the method hideactivityindicator() should works, I copy your answer but I have error

Comment: I get this Cannot assign to property: 'someMethodFromParent' is a method

Comment: I just copy your answer

Comment: change 'let' to `var` when defining `someMethodFromParent `

Comment: what is someProperty var?, I think that I should define the someMethodFromParent as fun someMethodFromParent(){}

Comment: in you child controller put this `internal var someProperty: (() -> Void)!`

Comment: and when you create your child controller in your parent, assing the parent method into the child property like this  ```childVC.someMethodFromParent = hideActivityIndicator```

Comment: I have updated my answer to make it more clear and less ambiguous

Comment: but I should declare someMethodFromParent() as func?

Comment: yeah just declare a method in your parent the same way you would do it normally in you case would be this ```func hideActivityIndicator() {
    navigationItem.titleView = nil
} ```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181175/discussion-between-israel-and-pato-salazar).

Comment: I invite you to chat, please help me

Answer (score 1):

How about having a ChildViewControllerDelegate? Something like:

```
class ParentViewController {
    func someFunc(){
        ...
        childVC.delegate = self
        ...
    }
}

extension ParentViewController: ChildViewControllerDelegate {
    func childViewControllerDidFinishApiCall() {
        hideActivityIndicator()
    }
}

protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func childViewControllerDidFinishApiCall()
}

class ChildViewController {
    weak var delegate: ChildViewControllerDelegate?

    func call_api(){
        //code related to api
        let pctrl = ParentViewController()
        delegate?.childViewControllerDidFinishApiCall()
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'ChildViewControllerDelegate'

Comment: oh, yes, see my updated answer: have `: class` in `ChildViewControllerDelegate` definition.

Comment: I do all your answer but does not work, the hideActivityIndicator() not works

Comment: I don't have errors but never is called the method hideActivityIndicator()